# Use keywords in column to determine which column to extract data from

Tags: python, pandas

i have the following data in a dataframe.

```
JAN FEB MAR 2019 MAR YTD    2018 MAR YTD
99.8    98.6    98.7    99.0    99.1
100.0   99.0    97.9    98.8    99.2
99.5    98.0    99.7    99.2    99.9
100.0   97.2    98.9    98.5    100.0
100.0   100.0   100.0   100.0   100.0
100.0   94.7    100.0   98.7    99.5
97.6    100.0   100.0   99.3    100.0
100.0   96.6    100.0   99.2    100.0
100.0   97.0    99.4    99.1    97.3
100.0   98.2    100.0   99.6    97.0
100.0   86.7    94.6    94.8    99.9
100.0   100.0   99.5    99.7    98.5
100.0   100.0   100.0   100.0   97.9
100.0   100.0   100.0   100.0   98.9
100.0   100.0   97.1    98.5    99.6
100.0   100.0   100.0   100.0   98.2
100.0   100.0   100.0   100.0   98.1
```

I will like to extract a specific column data if the value in row 1 contains the word "YTD". 
I want to use a keyword search rather than column and row cell reference. 
I will also like the code to break after the first "YTD" value is identified.

Because, am using openplex and panda to extract and write the data. I used the following code:
min_column=report_sheet1.min_column

for j in range(row=6,column=min_column+1):
        if 'YTD' in j:
            break

ff_sheet1.cell(row=insert_col + start_row,column = header['YTD'], value=report_sheet1.cell(row=i + 0, column=j).value)

But then, i get an "range() takes no keyword arguments" error

I do not know how to go about this. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You can iterate over the columns using `df.columns`. something like - `for k in df.columns:` And using a `break` logic, you can extract the first column that satisfies your conditions.

Comment: You should always include some code as to how you got this far.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) could be useful! Maybe you could do something along the lines of the following:

```
import re

c = [label for label in dataframe.columns if re.search('YTD', label) != None]
```

That should provide a list of the columns whose labels contain the substring 'YTD.'

I'm not too familiar with pandas, so there might be an easier way than what I suggested. I'm not sure if this fully answers your question, but maybe it helps!

Comment: No need for a regex. `if 'YTD' in label` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a single line:

```
[df[x] for x in df.columns if 'YTD' in x][0]
```

Will give you the first column matching your requirements

Comment: Because, am using openplex and panda to extract and write the data. I used the following code: min_column=report_sheet1.min_column

for j in range(row=6,column=min_column+1): if 'YTD' in j: break

ff_sheet1.cell(row=insert_col + start_row,column = header['YTD'], value=report_sheet1.cell(row=i + 0, column=j).value)

But then, i get an "range() takes no keyword arguments" error